# Writing a Makefile.am to invoke googletest unit tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, makefile, automake, googletest

I am trying to add my first unit test to an existing Open Source project. Specifically, I added a new class, called audio_manager:

```
src/audio/audio_manager.h
src/audio/audio_manager.cc
```

I created a src/test directory structure that mirrors the structure of the implementation files, and wrote my [googletest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) unit tests:

```
src/test/audio/audio_manager.cc
```

Now, I am trying to set up my Makefile.am to compile and run the unit test:

```
src/test/audio/Makefile.am
```

I copied Makefile.am from:

```
src/audio/Makefile.am
```

Does anyone have a simple recipe for me, or is it to the cryptic automake documentation for me? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

William's answer got me where I needed to go. Just for the sake of the community, here's what I ended up doing:

1. I moved my tests back into the main directory structure and prepended test_, as per William's suggestions.
2. I added a few lines to src/audio/Makefile.am to enable unit tests:

   ```
   # Unit tests
   noinst_PROGRAMS = test_audio_manager

   test_audio_manager_SOURCES  = $(libadonthell_audio_la_SOURCES) test_audio_manager.cc
   test_audio_manager_CXXFLAGS = $(libadonthell_audio_la_CXXFLAGS)
   test_audio_manager_LDADD    = $(libadonthell_audio_la_LIBADD) -lgtest

   TESTS = test_audio_manager
   ```
3. Now, running "make check" fires the unit tests!

All of this can be seen here: http://github.com/ksterker/adonthell/commit/aacdb0fe22f59e61ef0f5986827af180c56ae9f3

Answer (score 9):

If the existing project already has a test structure in place, then you should just add:

```
TESTS += audio_manager
```

to the existing tests/Makefile.am.  If the existing project does not have a test structure in place, you should run screaming for the hills.

If running for the hills is not acceptable, there's a fair bit of work in getting the test structure in place, but it's not insurmountable.  You might prefer to make tests a sibling of src, but that's not necessary.  It's probably easier to start with a fresh Makefile.am rather than copying the Makefile.am from src, but maybe not.  Possibly, all you'll need to do is change lines of the form:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = ...
```

to

```
check_PROGRAMS = ...
```

add the line

```
TESTS = test-audio-manager
```

change the name of audio_manager.cc to test-audio-manager.cc (that's not strictly necessary, but will help maintainability.  I changed _ to - purely out of personal preference) and add a

```
SUBDIRS = tests/audio
```

to src/Makefile.am.  (If there's already a SUBDIRS directive, append to that assignment or use +=)

Comment: Kudos to you for getting everyone there to begin with :)

Answer (score 2):

Complimenting the information in the other answers, you can also specify multiple tests to `TESTS`.

Regardless of how many tests you specify, you don't actually have to specify them twice, instead just set `TESTS` to `$(check_PROGRAMS)` - this can help to prevent an accidental situation of adding your test to `check_PROGRAMS` but forgetting to add it to `TESTS`, causing your new test to be added to the build, but never being run by `make check`:

```
# Unit tests
check_PROGRAMS = test_audio_manager

test_audio_manager_SOURCES  = test_audio_manager.cc

TESTS = $(check_PROGRAMS)
```

...or to do the same with multiple tests:

```
# Unit tests
check_PROGRAMS = test_audio_manager test_video_manager

test_audio_manager_SOURCES  = test_audio_manager.cc
test_video_manager_SOURCES  = test_video_manager.cc

TESTS = $(check_PROGRAMS)
```